# Any date 1 year from between selected dates MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

I am building a report for people who signed up 1 year ago.

I want to run this report at a given time. So anyone that has been a member for 1 year between two dates.

It's a form with between date1 and date2 with a submit.

So if i want to see anyone who has been a member between 01-08-2014 and 01-10-2014 as an example. Anyone that would have been or was a member between those dates show in a list.

So far i have this but its not displaying any records:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `nfw_users` 
WHERE DATE(date_join) BETWEEN 2012-05-20 
      AND 2012-10-20 AND date_join >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Comment: Is it a typo or you are really missing quotes around date like '2012-05-20'

Comment: no difference, still shows zero records.

Comment: Also the provided date values are of year **2012** and your second condition is checking for **2013** for same column which is producing 0 results either you have to provide date range which will be greater than the result of `DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below query and you are missing quotes around date like "2012-05-20"

```
SELECT * 
FROM `nfw_users` 
WHERE DATE(date_join) BETWEEN "2013-05-20" AND "2013-10-20"
AND YEAR(date_join) = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Comment: Sorry thats not it either. 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4

Comment: MySQL will not be able to make use of an index range scan operation on columns that are wrapped in functions. Also, this query pattern is broken (by design) in the more general case, with date range interval that spans a year boundary `'2012-11-15'` and `'2013-01-15'`. I see that this is the selected answer, but I don't see how any rows can satisfy the predicates in this query. date_join in 2012 and date_join in 2013.

Comment: @spencer7593: Thank you for correcting me but I don't think there is an index on date_join. Moreover may I know what's the issue with date range interval. Date "2012-05-20" AND "2012-10-20" can be changed i guess

Comment: @Rockse: what value of date_join can satisfy the predicates in this query, given that NOW() returns a date value in 2014. What value of `date_join` is going to be between two dates in 2012 and also be in the year 2013? The issue I was pointing out that in the more general case, when boundary dates of the BETWEEN range could be in two different years. And the predicate on YEAR(date_join) guarantees that `join_date` from both years cannot be returned.

Comment: @Rockse: with the edit to change the literals in the BETWEEN predicate, from 2012 to 2014, it's still impossible for this query to return any rows, at least for a couple more months, when NOW() returns a date value in 2015.

Comment: well it does work guys. Maybe its not meant to in theory. But it is working

Answer (score 1):

Likely the literals `2012-05-20` and `2012-10-20` in your query are evaluating to NULL in a "date"  context. (That's valid syntax, but likely not what you want.)

Date literals should be enclosed in single quotes, e.g.

```
    ... BETWEEN '2012-05-20' AND '2012-10-20' 
                ^          ^     ^          ^
```

---

As of right now ('2014-10-14 06:36:36'), this predicate:

```
date_join >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

is equivalent to:

```
date_join >= '2013-10-14 06:36:36'
```

That means that no rows with `date_join` less than that value will be returned, so no rows can be returned, since there are no `date_join` values that are greater than `'2013-10-14'` that are also less than or equal to `'2012-10-20'`. The predicates in your query make it impossible for any rows to match.

Your specification is a little ambiguous. Some example data, and which rows you expect to be returned would go a long ways towards clarifying the specification. You want to return rows for individuals who were members for exactly one year, or at least one year, within a given date range?

To return rows for "members" who hit a one year anniversary sometime between two specific dates:

```
WHERE date_join >= '2013-05-20' + INTERVAL -1 YEAR
  AND date_join <  '2013-10-20' + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL -1 YEAR
```

To return rows for "members" who have been (or would have been) members for at least a full year between two dates, I don't see that two boundaries would be required for that, a check against a single lower bound date would be sufficient.

Comment: @Elgoots according to the question this one provides the answer

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid: I concur with your comments on the OP question. We typically prefer to refer to bare columns in the predicates in the WHERE clause (to allow MySQL the option to use an efficient range scan operation), and do any required manipulation on the constant side of the predicate. The specification is a bit unclear to me, even more so now, since the query in the selected answer is guaranteed to return zero rows; it's impossible for any values of `date_join` to satisfy the predicates. (Given that NOW() returns a date value in 2014.)

Comment: @spencer7593 I do agree with you that at same time single column can't satisfy 2 completely different cases but accepting an answer depends on OP we can't force him/her to accept the right answer other thing is i have already up voted your answer SO doesn't allow me to up vote it twice :),Leave it on OP's choice i guess they are here to get their work done they don't wanna learn